# How to refer to django foreign key?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I used to use a OneToOneField relation to the User model, but I had to switch to foreign key (because I want to store multiple dates for 1 user). And now I can't seem to figure out how to refer to my data inside my view.

view.py

```py
def get_data(request, *args,**kwargs):
    data = {
        'weight': request.user.user_profile.weight,
        'goal': request.user.user_profile.goal,
        'date': request.user.user_profile.created_at,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    goal = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep OneToOne field. If you want multiple dates you can create ForeignKey for the dates.

If you still want ForeignKey Profile-User, you can try to filter the Profile model, to get the particular profile you need, by username, date etc.:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user, created_at=request.user.date_joined)

data = {
        'weight': profile.weight,
        'goal': profile.goal,
        'date': profile.created_at,
    }
```